# Include a jade file with the use of a session variable

Tags: include, pug

I am developing a web application that have 3 different acctypes.
Student teacher and admin.
Depending on what acctype is logged in I wan't to load different menus.
I have acctype assigned to a session variable;
    `#{session.acctype}`

So I used to handle it like this;
    `script(src='js/sidebar#{session.acctype}.js')`

But I wanted to get rid of the use of document.write that I used in the js file that was loaded above. 
So now I have the menu in a jade file inside.

Here comes the problem, I don't know how to use the session variable to load a jade file!
I tried this without any success;
    `include sidebar#{session.acctype}.jade`

So, is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 5):

In order to give your templates access to your session variables, you need to add them to `res.session.locals`. An easy way to accomplish this is by adding

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
```

to your application before you call `app.use(app.router)`. This technique is called using middleware.